# How to use tokenSession in struts2?

Tags: struts2

I have implemented `tokenSession` and 
it works perfect for multiple Form submission (for example while refereshing the url). But I have a signUp Modal where I am Validating (From server! Hits the Action Class) the verification code(ex:38292) through ajax... If the Code is wrong it returns Invalid Code! And if I give right code and resubmits again it throw Warning:

> WARNING: Form token HGWQI7ZGP7KFGJLDPNTSFHLUX5RF26IK does not match the session token null.

I understood it's a second request for server... But from user prospective it should take request! I don't want to disable submit button. Is there any other solution in Struts2 or better way to implement?

Expected: User submits form and server is slow or user clicks multiple time the request should not go (works fine!). But if user putting invalid code (which goes to Action and returns invalid) and user puts right code resubmitting form the request should go.

Comment: That check with ajax you're talking about... don't submit the whole form.

Comment: @AleksandrM Oh i need to have two action one for checking code and other action for doing second task...??

Comment: If you want to have token in form for preventing multiple form submissions and to check some field with ajax then yes having two actions seems like what you need.

Comment: @Gopi Lal I think two actions is not a right way to solve this problem.

Comment: @gopalgupta If not the right way.!Please give the Alternative solution...

Comment: @Gopi Lal  Its useful only when you are using js validation, not  when you are using  struts action validation.
You need to hit the server everytime to check the validation and data.
Use cannot use this here.

Comment: @gopalgupta: Stop confusing OP. They already using ajax.